# the best way to link web pages and content with javascript (or not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

My question is pretty straight forward although no doubt I will get some varied responses all of which are welcome...

I have built a site that on this occasion loads content from pages into an index file using javascript.  My question is , is this method ok to use when considering how search engines rank sites based on multiple links to other pages for content... so for example if i had a bit of code like this...

```
$(".container-indexpage").load("company-contact-page-content.html #some-content");
```

This is great because i am loading the content from all my webpages (which are just full of divs with content) into the container on my index page, making transition and housekeeping and a few other things work well for me.

would using this way and not having to link a tags to whole html pages with similar design but specific content be ok by google... So if google is not keen on the use of javascript in this way it may just list the index page on ranking and this is essentially what i am worried about.. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally google renders the full page, so I don't think this would have a negative effect on the search engine. That being said, all the calls seem like a bad idea in terms of being user-friendly. A lot of loading and server traffic that way.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will test it with goggle analytics to see if the pages register as opposed to just the index page, the pain of creating cool javascript hopefully wont be for nothing !

Comment: You can always accept the answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: actually a bit worried about it now as my content from the other html pages is being pulled via javascript into the index file my analytics is only showing the index page as the only one visited , do you think this would be a problem Jan ?

Comment: That might be a problem for sitelinks etc. but for the content itself it is not.

Comment: i guess that being the case i can circumvent the problem bby using ga.js